# A complex manifold isn't a sympletic manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

I want to think about an example of a complex manifold which isn't a sympletic manifold. I consider it in this way: $X=\mathbb{C}^2-\{0\}$, a group $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on X by $(n,z)=2^nz$, then I think that $X/\mathbb{Z}$ is a complex manifold which isn't a sympletic manifold, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Hint: What is $H^2(X/\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: @John I think I need to prove $H^2(X/\mathbb{Z})=0$ and X/\mathbb{Z} is closed manifold, but I don't how to prove it.

Comment: Can you (Yui) identify the diffeomorphism type of $X$?

Comment: What is "diffeomorphism type"? Is it the invariant for closed, smooth 4-manifolds which is introduced by Donaldson? @user86418

Comment: To rephrase, do you know which well-known $4$-manifold is diffeomorphic to $X$? If not, it may help to observe $\mathbf{C}^{2} - \{0\}$ is diffeomorphic to $S^{3} \times \mathbf{R}$.

Comment: So $X/\mathbb{Z} \cong S^3 \times S^1$, and $H^2(S^3 \times S^1)=0$, isn't it? @user86418

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your manifold $(\Bbb{C}^2 - \{0\})/\Bbb Z$ is known as the **Hopf surface** and it is indeed diffeomorphic to $S^3 \times S^1$. Now $H^2(S^3 \times S^1) = 0$ so that every closed $2$-form on the Hopf surface is exact. Since the Hopf surface is a closed manifold, Stokes' theorem implies that it admits no symplectic form (symplectic forms on closed manifolds cannot be exact).